# Why was my suggested edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

For some reason, the questioner elected to take screenshots of the terminal, instead of copying and pasting. This means that (a) the question is slower to load, (b) the question is inaccessible to people using screen readers, and (c) the screenshotted portions are not searchable. Furthermore, the terminal in question has a funky background image, which makes it quite hard to read for anyone with any degree of visual impairment.

So [I transcribed the images to improve accessibility](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/228683). Why on *earth* was this edit rejected?

(Incidentally, I don’t care tuppence for rep points. I just enjoy editing.)

Comment: Ask OP. He was the one that rejected the edit...

Comment: Yeah, @Braiam. I'd just realised that.

Comment: @Braiam, you beat me to applying the edit, hehe.. and yes, that background was annoying.

Comment: Here! Have an upvote on one of your SO answers! Well-deserved

Comment: Relevant: [Why do people post screenshots of their terminals?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713)

Comment: Not so impressed with rejection itself, as with *This edit is too minor* “reason”. How many more such stupid dropdown-menu-pushes yet to occur before StackExchange will finally decide to reform so named “review” feature?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I had to guess, because the OP liked their pictures. It can sometimes be hard to be objective when somebody comes along and edits your stuff. It's certainly a strange feeling.

Your edit was solid work though, it really improved the post and it should have been accepted.